I am facing issue deploying my NODE JS App on Firebase (Without using functions)
I have a node js app running successfully on Render, but I am looking to forward to leave Render and use Firebase for hosting.
All the youtube tutorials are using firebase init function command line.
Due to which they are creating a functions folder in the node js app. Which I find unnecessary.
What I want is:- I want to connect the firebase project to my github repository where the node js app is hosted. I want the firebase project to automatically pull the repository and update itself (Just like how render does). I want the Firebase hosted app URL. And directly use it in my frontend to make API calls.
Please Note:- I have developed my Node Js app using Express and Mongoose
I have selected the "web app" option in the Firebase project that I have created to run my NODE js app.
Please help! Thankyou!
